# How do we get around PostgreSQL autovacuum taking a table-level lock ACCESS EXCLUSIVE on replicas?

Tags: postgresql, locking, vacuum

We are running:

```
user@primary/client-n:~$ psql -d database -c "SELECT version();"                                                                   
version
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 10.7 (Ubuntu 10.7-1.pgdg16.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

on:

```
user@primary/client-n:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

and have a setup with one primary and two streaming replication clients configured with:

```
user@client-n:~$ psql -d postgres -c "SELECT name, setting FROM pg_settings WHERE name IN ( 'hot_standby', 'hot_standby_feedback', 'max_standby_streaming_delay' );"
           name             | setting 
----------------------------+---------
hot_standby                 | on
hot_standby_feedback        | on
max_standby_streaming_delay | 150000
(3 rows)
```

We have one database only (other than the standard ones) and one table in the database. Approximately 3 to 4 times per day we run into a special case autovacuum situation which is described in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/routine-vacuuming.html) as:

> [...] it (autovacuum) will not return the space to the operating system, except in the special case where one or more pages at the end of a table become entirely free and an exclusive table lock can be easily obtained

We are monitoring `pg_locks` and have been able to observe the autovacuum daemon taking the table-level lock `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` which in turn leads to a whole host of blocked processes on the clients as illustrated with the log entries below:

Primary:

```
...
2019-06-04 05:59:29.154 BST [8998-1] LOG:  automatic vacuum of table "database.schema.table": index scans: 1
...
```

Client 1:

```
...
2019-06-04 05:59:03.660 BST [21167-858] [PostgreSQL JDBC Driver@ip_address(port):role@database] | LOG:  process 21167 still waiting for AccessShareLock on relation 16390 of database 16388 after 1000.222 ms
2019-06-04 05:59:03.660 BST [21167-859] [PostgreSQL JDBC Driver@ip_address(port):role@database] | DETAIL:  Process holding the lock: 2741. Wait queue: 21167, 1215, 26415.
2019-06-04 05:59:03.660 BST [21167-860] [PostgreSQL JDBC Driver@ip_address(port):role@database] | STATEMENT:  SELECT ...
2019-06-04 05:59:03.730 BST [1215-51] [PostgreSQL JDBC Driver@ip_address(port):role@database] | LOG:  process 1215 still waiting for AccessShareLock on relation 16390 of database 16388 after 1000.188 ms at character 15
2019-06-04 05:59:03.730 BST [1215-52] [PostgreSQL JDBC Driver@ip_address(port):role@database] | DETAIL:  Process holding the lock: 2741. Wait queue: 21167, 1215, 26415.
2019-06-04 05:59:03.730 BST [1215-53] [PostgreSQL JDBC Driver@ip_address(port):role@database] | STATEMENT:  SELECT ...
...
2019-06-04 05:59:19.975 BST [22242-4569] [PostgreSQL JDBC Driver@ip_address(port):role@database] | LOG:  process 22242 still waiting for AccessShareLock on relation 16390 of database 16388 after 1000.281 ms at character 15
2019-06-04 05:59:19.975 BST [22242-4570] [PostgreSQL JDBC Driver@ip_address(port):role@database] | DETAIL:  Process holding the lock: 2741. Wait queue: 21167, 1215, 26415, 2423, 1289, 24009, 22441, 2640, 1843, 1056, 23336, 28060, 1860, 1134, 19419, 14649, 2721, 29540, 20138, 22242.
2019-06-04 05:59:19.975 BST [22242-4571] [PostgreSQL JDBC Driver@ip_address(port):role@database] | STATEMENT:  SELECT...
...
```

And the process holding the lock:

```
postgres=# SELECT pid, backend_type, wait_event_type, wait_event FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE pid = 2741;
 pid  | backend_type | wait_event_type |   wait_event
------+--------------+-----------------+----------------
 2741 | startup      | Activity        | RecoveryWalAll
(1 row)
```

[image]

Client 2:

```
...
2019-06-04 06:00:08.964 BST [16153-1] [PostgreSQL JDBC Driver@ip_address(port):role@database] | FATAL:  terminating connection due to conflict with recovery
2019-06-04 06:00:08.964 BST [16153-2] [PostgreSQL JDBC Driver@ip_address(port):role@database] | DETAIL:  User was holding a relation lock for too long.
2019-06-04 06:00:08.964 BST [16153-3] [PostgreSQL JDBC Driver@ip_address(port):role@database] | HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2019-06-04 06:00:09.964 BST [5747-537] [PostgreSQL JDBC Driver@ip_address(port):role@database] | LOG:  process 5747 still waiting for AccessShareLock on relation 16390 of database 16388 after 1000.248 ms
2019-06-04 06:00:09.964 BST [5747-538] [PostgreSQL JDBC Driver@ip_address(port):role@database] | DETAIL:  Process holding the lock: 12709. Wait queue: 5747, 19765, 16036, 14617, 12280, 14513, 14728, 15398, 27611, 14542, 15948, 23398, 5853, 5098, 4324, 10760, 23480, 30192, 15300, 16228.
2019-06-04 06:00:09.964 BST [5747-539] [PostgreSQL JDBC Driver@ip_address(port):role@database] | STATEMENT:  SELECT ...
2019-06-04 06:00:09.975 BST [19765-6847] [PostgreSQL JDBC Driver@ip_address(port):role@database] | LOG:  process 19765 still waiting for AccessShareLock on relation 16390 of database 16388 after 1000.180 ms
2019-06-04 06:00:09.975 BST [19765-6848] [PostgreSQL JDBC Driver@ip_address(port):role@database] | DETAIL:  Process holding the lock: 12709. Wait queue: 5747, 19765, 16036, 14617, 12280, 14513, 14728, 15398, 27611, 14542, 15948, 23398, 5853, 5098, 4324, 10760, 23480, 30192, 15300, 16228.
2019-06-04 06:00:09.975 BST [19765-6849] [PostgreSQL JDBC Driver@ip_address(port):role@database] | STATEMENT:  SELECT ...
...
2019-06-04 06:01:25.487 BST [15873-1] [PostgreSQL JDBC Driver@ip_address(port):role@database] | LOG:  process 15873 still waiting for AccessShareLock on relation 16390 of database 16388 after 1000.218 ms at character 15
2019-06-04 06:01:25.487 BST [15873-2] [PostgreSQL JDBC Driver@ip_address(port):role@database] | DETAIL:  Process holding the lock: 12709. Wait queue: 5747, 19765, 16036, 14617, 12280, 14513, 14728, 15398, 27611, 14542, 15948, 23398, 5853, 5098, 4324, 10760, 23480, 30192, 15300, 16228, 16127, 16285, 15873.
2019-06-04 06:01:25.487 BST [15873-3] [PostgreSQL JDBC Driver@ip_address(port):role@database] | STATEMENT:  SELECT ...
...
2019-06-04 06:01:29.160 BST [16127-6] [PostgreSQL JDBC Driver@ip_address(port):role@database] | LOG:  process 16127 acquired AccessShareLock on relation 16390 of database 16388 after 8560.748 ms at character 15
2019-06-04 06:01:29.160 BST [16127-7] [PostgreSQL JDBC Driver@ip_address(port):role@database] | STATEMENT:  SELECT ...
...
```

And the process holding the lock, again:

```
postgres=# SELECT pid, backend_type, wait_event_type, wait_event FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE pid = 2741;
 pid  | backend_type | wait_event_type |   wait_event
------+--------------+-----------------+----------------
12709 | startup      | Activity        | RecoveryWalAll
(1 row)
```

[image]

The blocked queries on the clients lead to API latency of between 10 to 20 seconds and occasionally, a high number of 5xx responses. Out SRE team has been tasked with bringing the API latency during these incidents down and we are looking for ways of resolving this what we understand to be a very niche situation. We are currently experimenting with `recovery_min_apply_delay = 120s` on client 1 (hence the later log entries)  so that both clients do not lock up at the same time. This has somewhat reduced he number of erroneous responses and lowered the latency spikes a bit. We are unsure about how to go about resolving this issue fully, and in fact, whether it is possible to do so. We would appreciate your advice. We have found [this related post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/205130/autovacuum-gets-exclusive-lock-and-replayed-in-the-slave-and-lead-to-system-faul), but sadly, it hasn't been resolved either.

Comment: Have you considered manually vacuuming under cron control? [See Routine Vacuuming](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/routine-vacuuming.html) Have you considered all the settings under [autovacuum](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/runtime-config-autovacuum.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One undocumented way of avoiding `VACUUM` truncation and the exclusive lock it requires is to set `old_snapshot_threshold` to a value other than -1. This in turn will get rid of the locks and the resulting recovery conflicts. However, note that the implementation of `old_snapshot_threshold` had problems, and the parameter has been removed in PostgreSQL v17.

From PostgreSQL v12 on you can use the better technique of disabling `VACUUM` truncation for individual tables:

```
ALTER TABLE mytab
   SET (vacuum_truncate = on,
        toast.vacuum_truncate = on);
```

Comment: We are going to give `old_snapshot_threshold` a try and post an update with how we get on. I found a recommendation for what to set `old_snapshot_threshold` to i.e., "the length of the longest transaction you expect to run + 1 hour" here https://postgresqlco.nf/en/doc/param/old_snapshot_threshold?version=10. Does this sound like a good place to start?

Comment: Sure. You don't want it to interfere with your application.

Comment: What is the difference between `old_snapshot_threshold = -1` (freed space at the end of a relation can be released to the OS when `autovacuum` can easily obtain an exclusive table lock), versus, `old_snapshot_threshold = 0m` (freed space at the end of a relation can be released to the OS after 0 minutes, i.e., immediately)?

Comment: `old_snapshot_threshold` actually serves a different purpose that has nothing to do with truncation: it determines which tuples can be vacuumed. It is a side effect that is determined by the implementation that setting it prevents vacuum truncation. There is no logical connection.

Comment: we only enable `old_snapshot_threshold` on the primary, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, of course. `VACUUM` only happens on the primary.

Comment: This is just a quick update to say that we enabled `old_snapshot_threshold ` just under a week ago (setting it to 2 hours) and haven't experienced any `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` locks caused by autovacuum since making the change.

Comment: I can also verify that we had the same issue and it was solved by setting ours to our longest query, which for us, because we do backups from a standby, it was the longest query and we added safety time of a few hours on top of that.  It's been 6 months without further issue.

Comment: @Diane Note the `old_snapshot_threshold` has been removed in PostgreSQL v17.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe So what's the alternative in v17?  We have large multi-terabyte tables that are highly active that currently depend on this feature for exactly these reasons.  I don't like the idea of turning off `vacuum_truncate` because that means we won't be able to claim back space from the OS and we run long backups on one of the standbys, which can also cause this issue.  We also have several tables in several servers in this state and I was looking for something that could be applied as a general setting vs, having to apply it on each specific table.

Comment: Also note I asked a similar question in https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/323724/postgresql-12-streaming-replication-standbys-timing-out-due-to-autovacuum-tasks with all steps we took.  This was the only thing that helped out of everything we tried.

Comment: @Diane There is no alternative. This was never an intended and documented side effect of `old_snapshot_threshold`. You'll have to set `vacuum_truncate = off` on all tables. Note that `VACUUM (FULL)` still shrinks such tables.

Comment: We are a 24/7 site and cannot take a full vacuum on an active production table, especially one that large that would basically block for hours.  I guess this means we can't upgrade until Postgres provides a better  solution.

Comment: @Diane I don't understand. You say that you used `old_snapshot_threshold` to *avoid* `VACUUM` truncation so that you don't get canceled queries on the standby. So setting `vacuum_truncate = off` on all tables would do the trick just as well. No matter what, you cannot shrink tables without taking a lock that will cancel queries on the standby.

Comment: Can you verify whether old_snapshot_threshold prevents truncation entirely, or only on dead tuples newer than the threshold?  The documentation doesn’t make that clear and my assumption was the latter case.  If indeed truncation is turned off entirely either way, we can make that change when we upgrade to v17.

Comment: @Diane I think it prevents `VACUUM` truncation entirely, but I am too lazy to check the source right now. In many cases you can do just fine without `VACUUM` truncation.